# Why should I check for null before I invoke the custom event?

Tags: c#, events

What is the difference between these two code samples for invoking an event?

Sample 1

```
public void OnDataChanged()
{
    if (DataChanged != null)
    {
        DataChanged(this);
    }
}
```

Sample 2

```
DataChanged.Invoke(this);
```

When should I use each method to invoke a custom event? And why sometimes I get a NullReferenceException when I try to invoke event using `DataChanged.Invoke(this)`, but when I convert the event invocation to the method in Sample 1 the `DataChanged` never becomes null anymore?

Comment: In C# 6.0 I suggest to use: `DataChanged?.Invoke(this);`

Comment: `DataChanged(this);` is just shorthand for `DataChanged.Invoke(this);` They do the same thing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An `OnXYZ` method should always follow this form:

```
public void OnXYZ()
{
    var evt = XYZ;
    if (evt != null)
        evt(sender, e); // where to get e from differs
}
```

There are a couple of reasons for this form:

1. The `if evt != null` check ensures that we don't try to invoke a `null` delegate. This can happen if nobody has hooked up an event handler to the event.
2. In a multithreaded scenario, since delegates are immutable, once we've obtained a local copy of the delegate into `evt`, we can safely invoke it after checking for non-null, since nobody can alter it after the `if` but before the call.

What to pass for `e` differs, if you need to pass an `EventArgs` descendant with a parameter there are two ways:

```
public void OnXYZ(string p)
{
    var evt = XYZ;
    if (evt != null)
        evt(sender, new SomeEventArgs(p));
}
```

or more commonly this:

```
public void OnXYZ(SomeEventArgs e)
{
    var evt = XYZ;
    if (evt != null)
        evt(sender, e);
}
```

This syntax:

```
evt(sender, e);
```

is just a different way of writing this:

```
evt.Invoke(sender, e);
```

Also note that externally to your class, the event is an event, you can only `add` or `remove` event handlers from it.

Internal to your class, the event is a delegate, you can invoke it, check the target or method, walk the list of subscribers, etc.

---

Also, in C# 6 there is a new operator introduced, `?.` - the [Null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) - which is basically short for `if not-null, dereference`, which can shorten this method:

```
public void OnXYZ(SomeEventArgs e)
{
    var evt = XYZ;
    if (evt != null)
        evt(sender, e);
}
```

into this:

```
public void OnXYZ(SomeEventArgs e)
{
    XYZ?.Invoke(sender, e);
}
```

which can be further shortened with the use of Expression-bodied members:

```
public void OnXYZ(SomeEventArgs e) => XYZ?.Invoke(sender, e);
```

Please note that it is not possible to write this:

```
XYZ?.(sender, e);
```

so you must in this case use `Invoke` yourself.

Answer (score 2):

> when I convert the event invocation to the method in Sample 1 the DataChanged never becomes Null

Then you're simply looking at two different scenarios.

if you don't declare an event like `public event EventHandler YourEvent = delegate { };`, then `YourEvent` is `null` until some consumer subscribes to it.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing has subscribed to DataChanged it will be set to null, and so when you attempt to do DataChanged.Invoke(this) you'll get a NullRefException as really it's trying to do null.Invoke(this). The reason for the additional if (DataChanged != null) is to avoid this occurring when nobody has subscribed to the event.

I don't believe that when you use Sample 1 DataChanged is never null, it's just never reaching the .Invoke to throw up the exception. It will always be null if nobody has subscribed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, that in Sample 1 the `DataChanged` is never null? Or you just don't get the NullReference Exception (because you check if `DataChanged` **is not null** in the `if` statement)?

Let's start with the basics. Event is a special kind of delegate. When you call DataChanged(this) and DataChanged.Invoke(this), it's the same thing. Why? Because it compiles to the same thing. So all in all the `DataChanged(this)` is just a shorthand for calling `DataChanged.Invoke(this)`.

Now, why do we need to check for null reference (like in sample 1).
Basically, when you invoke an event, you invoke all methods that were subscribed to this event (e.g. `DataChanged += someEventHandler`).
If nobody subscribed to this event, it will have a `null` value. No method was assigned to handle this event. In other words: the event handler is null.

That's why it's a good practice to check for null, before invoking an event.

Answer (score 0):

An Example:

```
public void OnAbc(){
    var data=Abc;

    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        Abc(sender,e);
}
```